# Trying to import "ALAssetRepresentation.h " in Xcode gives me symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

Tags: objective-c, xcode, import, alassetslibrary, armv7

I'm trying to do work with the AssetsLibrary in objective c, but even doing a simple import gets me problems.

My imports look like:

```
   #import <AssetsLibrary/ALAsset.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/ALAssetsLibrary.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/ALAssetRepresentation.h>
```

If I delete the ALAssetRepresentation.h import, everything works fine, but I'm left with an empty forward class object that I can't use at all.  I know I'm not misspelling anything, since I went out of my way to just copy and paste the class reference ALAsset has to ALAssetRepresentation.

What's going on here?  Cleaning doesn't seem to help at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from error description follows that you probably did not link your project with `AssetsLibrary.framework` - to do that go in you target settings/Build phases and add that framework in "Link binary with libraries" section:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! None of the Asset Library tutorials mentioned this! Much appreciated!